# Classic Probability Question: Is my method valid?

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am new to probability. The question is stated as follows:

"If a straight line is divided at two points which are chosen at random, what is the probability that the three newly formed line segments can form a triangle?"

I am aware of the two standard solutions using geometry and calculus respectively. Is my method correct?

My solution:

We first discuss a finite case, then derive the continuous case by way of limit. We will think of our straight line as the interval $[0, 1]$. Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and for integers $1 \leq k \leq 2n+1$, let $\omega_k = \frac{k}{2n+1}$ such that we have a partition 
\begin{align*}
    0=\omega_0<\omega_1<...<\omega_n < \frac{1}{2} < \omega_{n+1} < ... < \omega_{2n}<\omega_{2n+1}=1.
\end{align*}
Consider the sample space $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_{2n} \}$. We have $2n$ outcomes evenly spaced on $(0, 1)$ with $n$ outcomes in $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ and the remaining $n$ outcomes in $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an event space of $\Omega$ with probability measure $P_n$. We define $P_n$ to be uniform such that 
\begin{align*}
    P_n(\omega_1) &=P_n(\omega_2)=...=P_n(\omega_{2n})\\
    &=\frac{1}{2n}.
\end{align*}
Suppose we perform two consecutive experiments with outcomes $(\omega_i, \omega_j) \in \Omega \times \Omega$ which we have ordered such that $\omega_i \leq \omega_j$. What conditions must $\omega_i$ and $\omega_j$ satisfy such that the line segments $L_1=[0, \omega_i]$, $L_2=[\omega_i, \omega_j]$, and $L_3=[\omega_j, 1]$ form a triangle? Let $S_1, S_2,$ and $S_3$ denote the respective lengths of $L_1, L_2,$ and $L_3$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
    S_1 &= \omega_i,\\ S_2&=\omega_j-\omega_i,\\ S_3&=1-\omega_j.
\end{align*}
Note that we may form a triangle from $L_1, L_2,$ and $L_3$ if and only if the sum of the lengths of any two of these segments is greater than the length of the remaining segment. That is
\begin{align*}
    S_1+S_2&>S_3 \text{ and }\\
    S_1+S_3&>S_2 \text{ and }\\
    S_2+S_3&>S_1\\
    &\text{(if and only if)}\\
    \omega_i < \frac{1}{2} &< \omega_j \text{ and }\\
    \omega_j - \omega_i &< \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
This in mind, suppose we perform two consecutive experiments once anew and obtain outcomes $(\omega_i, \omega_j)\in \Omega \times \Omega$, this time ordered by chronology. Let "Triangle" denote the event that a triangle can be formed from the three line segments. By the basic principle of counting, we have $4n^2$ total equiprobable outcomes. By the law of total probability, we have
\begin{align*}
    P_n(\text{Triangle}) &=P_n(\text{Triangle and }  \omega_i<\omega_j)+P_n(\text{Triangle and } \omega_j < \omega_i)\\
    &=2P_n(\text{Triangle and } \omega_i<\omega_j).
\end{align*}
From our earlier observations, we conclude that 
\begin{align*}
    P_n(\text{Triangle})=2P_n\bigg(\omega_i < \frac{1}{2}<\omega_j\text{ and } \omega_j-\omega_i < \frac{1}{2}\bigg).
\end{align*}
By the law of total probability,
\begin{align*}
    P_n(\text{Triangle}) &= 2\sum_{i=1}^n P_n\bigg(  \frac{1}{2} < \omega_j \text{ and } \omega_j-\omega_i < \frac{1}{2} \bigg)\\
    &= \frac{2}{4n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n N\bigg( \frac{1}{2} < \omega_j \text{ and } \omega_j-\omega_i < \frac{1}{2}\bigg).
\end{align*}
For any $i$ in the sum above, $\omega_j \in \bigg\{ \frac{1}{2} < \omega_j \bigg\}\cap \bigg\{\omega_j-\omega_i < \frac{1}{2}\bigg\}$ only if $n< j < n+i $. So for each $i$ there are $i-1$ total choices of $j$. Therefore we have
\begin{align*}
    P_n(\text{Triangle}) &= \frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)\\
    &= \frac{1}{4} \frac{n-1}{n}.
\end{align*}
Let $P$ be the uniform distribution over $(0, 1)$. Arguing by continuity, 
\begin{align*}
    P(\text{ Triangle }) &=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(\text{ Triangle })\\
    &= \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}

Notes: I am using my intuition from calculus. I am sure the process of partitioning the domain is familiar to anyone who has ever glanced at an integral. What theorem(s) am I using in my last step where I say "arguing by continuity" ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all your solution but yes, the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$. I have a different and easy explanation.

Without loss of generality, let's say that the "straight line" is equal to 1. In this case, see the picture below

[image]

The 3 segment randomly chosen in this Uniform $U(0;1)$ distribution will form a Triangle if and only if the segment $\overline{ab}$ in picture is $<1/2$ AND it contains the average point $\frac{1}{2}$

1) The probability $\mathbb{P}[\overline{ab}<\frac{1}{2}]=\frac{1}{2}$ (trivial)

2) The probability $\mathbb{P}[x=\frac{1}{2} \in \overline{ab}]=\frac{1}{2}$ because it means that if $a <\frac{1}{2}$ then $b>\frac{1}{2}$ and viceversa.

***Concluding***: the requested probability is $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Good solution! This doesn't answer my question however. I would like to know if my method is valid. It is possible that I got the right answer by the wrong means.

Comment: I think the solution is incorrent. $P[ab < \frac{1}{2}] = \frac{3}{4}$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$: you can assume WLOG that point $a$ is in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and then valid $b$'s are in $[0, \frac{1}{2} + a]$, and as the average value of $a$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, they overall probability is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$. Additionally, events 1 and 2 are not necessarily independent (perhaps they are, but you should prove it if you think so)